# How can I get the last day of the previous month from a date entered?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm writing a stored procedure and the stored procedure requires a date to be entered:

`DECLARE @dateCurrent AS DATE = '10/31/2014'` // let's claim that '10/31/2014' is user input.

Based on this date entered I want to set this following variable to:

```
DECLARE @datePrior AS DATE = PreviousMonth(@dateCurrent)
```

Where  PreviousMonthLastDayOfPreviousMonth(@dateCurrent) == '9/30/2014'

So if a user enters '10/31/2014' it should set the following variable to '9/30/2014' which is effectively the last day of the previous month from the date entered.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what code have you tried so far?

Comment: Just FYI, if you run SQL Server 2012 above, SELECT EOMONTH(@dateCurrent,-1)

Comment: @ganders I tried EOMONTH() but discovered it was a 2012 server function not an 2008 r2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common way is to substract 1 day to the first day of the month:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,-1,CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),@dateCurrent,112)+'01')
```

Comment: but will this give me 9/30/2014? month and year included? 
I'm only asking because one of the parameters for dateadd in your suggestion is 'Day'

Comment: why don't you try it?, this returns a datetime, if you want a specific format, then you can convert it to a string or a date or whatever you want

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is:

```
DECLARE @date datetime = GETDATE()
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(@date)), @date)
```

This will subtract number of days past during the current month from today's day and return the date for the last day of the previous month.

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as Lamak, Date formatted though

```
  select dateadd(day,-1,DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM,0,GETDATE()),0))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @dateCurrent date =  '9/30/2014'

select DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, @dateCurrent)-1, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to convert the string to a date first.  Then you can use datediff to calculate the difference between now and the beginning of the input date's current month.  Add that difference to the input date and you have the end of the previous month.  Something like...

```
SELECT DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, CAST('10/31/2014' as datetime)),0))
```

Comment: The variable is defined as a `DATE` though, not as a string